# Redirect request to admin interface

Tags: django, django-admin, django-urls

After enabling the administrator interface and starting the
development web server on e.g. 128.0.0.1:8000, I am able to
reach the admin interface on

```
128.0.0.1:8000/admin.
```

Obviously due the following URL namespace

```
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)).
```

*What do I have to do redirect requests on 128.0.0.1:8000/ automatically to 128.0.0.1:8000/admin?*

The URL namespace

```
url(r'^$/', include(admin.site.urls))
```

does not seem to be the solution.

Comment: Good god. Found the error. Its " url(r'^$', include(admin.site.urls)) ". The single forward slash was responsible for the error. Spend way too much time on this. Thanks Daniel.

Comment: `url('', admin.site.urls),` in `urlpatterns` worked for me :)

Answer (score 20):

**Django 2.0** and above:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView


urlpatterns = [
    path('', RedirectView.as_view(url=reverse_lazy('admin:index'))),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Answer (score 17):

Use `RedirectView`. Instead of hardcoding URLs you can use [`reverse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse) and the name of an admin view.

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView

url(r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(url=reverse('admin:index')))
```

Comment: I had to use `reverse_lazy` instead of `reverse` as mentioned in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24680788/1797912). Otherwise I got an `ImproperlyConfigured` error (“The included urlconf […].urls doesn't have any patterns in it”).

Answer (score 9):

You say you want a **redirect** so you would use django's [`RedirectView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/#django.views.generic.base.RedirectView)

```
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView
url(r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/admin'))
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also use path instead of url which has been deprecated and is no longer available in Django 4.

```
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', RedirectView.as_view(url='/admin')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    ...
]
```

Answer (score 4):

This works for me. The `reverse_lazy` did not.

**Django 1.8.1 and above**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', lambda x: HttpResponseRedirect('/admin')),
)
```

Answer (score 4):

Previous solutions either show redirection to a hard-coded URL or use methods that didn't work here. This one **works in Django 1.9** and redirects to the admin index *view*:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

urlpatterns = patterns('',
  url(r'^$', lambda _: redirect('admin:index'), name='index'),
)
```

Comment: in django 2: `path('', lambda _: redirect('admin:index'), name="index")`

Comment: Agree with above comment for Django 2.1.   I used the redirect import and then path('', lambda _: redirect('admin:index'), name="index") not forgetting to add a comma on the end if added before the end of the url list!