# ImproperlyConfigured: The included urlconf <project>.urls doesn't have any patterns in it

Tags: django, apache

I have a django (1.6.x) project that runs fine with the dev server, but is failing under Apache2 (2.2.22.1) and mod_wsgi (3.3-4) on Ubuntu 12.04.3 with the error

ImproperlyConfigured: The included urlconf erp.urls doesn't have any patterns in it

I don't understand why it would work with the dev server but not Apache2/mod_wsgi and I'm finding it difficult to track down where the error is coming from.

There are a number of other SO questions similar, but the only place I use reverse (one problem previously found) is in get_absolute_url in my models - this should be fine?

The project is set up a la Two Scoops style, in particular the layout is:

`<repository_root>/<django_project_root>/<configuration_root>/`

which translates to:

`erp_root/erp/erp/`

and the settings are

`erp_root/erp/erp/settings/*py` (including the `__init__.py`)

erp/urls.py;

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'login.html'}),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'login.html'}, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout_then_login', {}, name='logout'),
    url(r'^search/', include('haystack.urls')),
    url(r'^inventory/', include('inventory.urls')),
)

if settings.DEBUG:
    import debug_toolbar
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
)
```

and inventory/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, patterns
from .forms import CarrierWizardForm1, CarrierWizardForm2, MovementWizardForm1,MovementWizardForm2
from . import views

carrier_wizard_forms = [CarrierWizardForm1, CarrierWizardForm2]
movement_wizard_forms = [MovementWizardForm1, MovementWizardForm2]

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.PartNumberListView.as_view(), name='inventory_list_index'),
    url(r'^parttype/$', views.part_type_list, name='index'),
    url(r'^parttype/(?P<parttype>\d{2})/$', views.part_type_view, name='part_type_view'),
    url(r'^partnumber/$', views.PartNumberListView.as_view(), name='partnumber_list'),
    url(r'^partnumber/add/$', views.PartNumberCreateView.as_view(), name='partnumber_add'),
    url(r'^partnumber/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.PartNumberView.as_view(), name='partnumber_view'),
    url(r'^partnumber/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/update/$', views.PartNumberUpdateView.as_view(), name='partnumber_update'),
    url(r'^partnumber/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/delete/$', views.PartNumberDeleteView.as_view(), name='partnumber_delete'),
    ....
       )
```

and erp/settings/dev.py:

```
# Django settings for erp project.
# settings.py

from unipath import Path

PROJECT_DIR = Path(__file__).ancestor(3)
MEDIA_ROOT = PROJECT_DIR.child("media")
STATIC_ROOT = PROJECT_DIR.child("static")
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
  PROJECT_DIR.child("assets"),
)
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
  PROJECT_DIR.child("templates"),
)


DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

TIME_ZONE = 'Australia/Melbourne'
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-au'
SITE_ID = 1
USE_TZ = True

DATE_FORMAT = 'd/m/y'
SHORT_DATE_FORMAT = 'd/m/y'

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://example.com/media/", "http://media.example.com/"
MEDIA_URL = ''

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/var/www/example.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = ''

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://example.com/static/", "http://static.example.com/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'stronghold.middleware.LoginRequiredMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'erp.urls'

# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'erp.wsgi.application'


INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.formtools',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'inventory',
    'django_extensions',
    'extra_views',
    'debug_toolbar',
    'django_tables2',
    'stronghold',
    'bootstrap3',
    'haystack',
)

LOGIN_URL = '/login'
LOGOUT_URL = '/logout'

# For Stronghold
STRONGHOLD_PUBLIC_NAMED_URLS = (
    'login',
    'logout',
)

# This is required by the debug toolbar middleware
INTERNAL_IPS = ('192.168.0.16','0.0.0.0','127.0.0.1','::1', '192.168.0.115')

# This is reqquired by django_tables2
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = ("django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                           "django.core.context_processors.debug",
                           "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
                           "django.core.context_processors.media",
                           "django.core.context_processors.static",
                           "django.core.context_processors.tz",
                           "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
                           "django.core.context_processors.request"
                          )
}

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/inventory/'

DEBUG_TOOLBAR_PANELS = [
'debug_toolbar.panels.versions.VersionsPanel',
'debug_toolbar.panels.timer.TimerPanel',
'debug_toolbar.panels.settings.SettingsPanel',
'debug_toolbar.panels.headers.HeadersPanel',
'debug_toolbar.panels.request.RequestPanel',
'debug_toolbar.panels.sql.SQLPanel',
'debug_toolbar.panels.staticfiles.StaticFilesPanel',
'debug_toolbar.panels.templates.TemplatesPanel',
'debug_toolbar.panels.cache.CachePanel',
'debug_toolbar.panels.signals.SignalsPanel',
'debug_toolbar.panels.logging.LoggingPanel',
]

def show_toolbar(request):
    return True  # Always show toolbar, for example purposes only.

DEBUG_TOOLBAR_CONFIG = {
'INTERCEPT_REDIRECTS': False,
'INSERT_BEFORE': '</body>',
'ENABLE_STACKTRACES': True,
}

# This is required for Haystack - the search engine
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
      'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.solr_backend.SolrEngine',
    'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:8085/solr/erp',
  },
}
```

My wsgi is the standard with minor settings mod:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "erp.settings.settings")
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

My apache2/sites-avail/erp.conf is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName deverp
   ServerAdmin administrator
   DocumentRoot /path/www/dev/erp/erp/
   ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/dev/error.log
   CustomLog /var/log/apache2/dev/access.log combined
   WSGIDaemonProcess deverp python-path=/path/www/dev/erp/erp:/path/.virtualenvs/erp-dev/lib/python2.7/site-packages
   WSGIProcessGroup deverp
   WSGIScriptAlias / /path/www/dev/erp/erp/erp/wsgi.py
  <Directory /path/www/dev/erp/erp/erp>
  <Files wsgi.py>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Files>
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: In erp/wsgi.py, try something like `import sys; import erp.urls; print >> sys.stderr, erp.urls.__file__` and then check your error log

Comment: add your apache vhost.conf

Comment: I got this error when upgrading django-debug-toolbar. Try the early version.

Comment: I get this error when I try to reverse a url from app/forms.py , while itworks in my models.py file and seems to work everywhere else. I get the ImproperlyConfigured at /admin/
The included urlconf my_project.urls doesn't have any patterns in it. I am trying to use the form in my admin views using get_form, I think this has something to do with it.

Comment: @radtek you need to see the other issues on SO about the reverse urls - that's more likely to be your issue. There are a number out there, as I note in my original question.

Comment: I saw your question but couldn't find anything regarding reversing url's from a form used in admin. My revese function works fine otherwise when used in other contexts. My workaround was to just use redirect('/myapp/my_view') without using reverse: redirect(reverse('url_name'))

Comment: I ran into the django-debug-toolbar issue, Zack how did you fix it?  [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/opt/python/current/app/site/lib/debug_toolbar/models.py", line 51, in patch_root_urlconf
[error] [client 127.0.0.1]     reverse('djdt:render_panel') . I'll see if the DEBUG_TOOLBAR_PATCH_SETTINGS = False  fixes it.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

So, I actually ran into a similar problem. Coincidentally after you posted in the issues for [django-stronghold](http://github.com/mgrouchy/django-stronghold). The issue is in fact due to a missing setting in django-debug-toolbar.

The setting you are missing is:

```
DEBUG_TOOLBAR_PATCH_SETTINGS = False
```

It will work with runserver, but if you try to run it with honcho, or gunicorn, or anything else that uses the WSGI interface it blows up.

EDIT: as mentioned below by @japhyr, its useful to check out the explicit setup instructions: http://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.org/en/1.0/installation.html#explicit-setup

Comment: Great find - I would never have tried that. Thanks, all working now.

Comment: DEBUG_TOOLBAR_PATCH_SETTINGS = False worked also for me. Thank you!

Comment: This solved the problem for me. Thank you so much. Like @datakid said, I would have never have tried this.

Comment: This was my core issue, but the suggestion here wasn't quite enough. I also had to follow the rest of the [Explicit setup](http://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.org/en/1.0/installation.html#explicit-setup) instructions for django-debug-toolbar.

Comment: i am confused about it so long, you just save me! Thx

Comment: Why DDT? Why?! You were supposed to improve my sanity! Not tear it pieces!

Comment: But now the debug toolbar is not running any more. Any help? Edit: Further down is the solution, in the comment of the last answer ( as of august 2014)

Comment: Also curious about the reason of this. Solved my problem as well.

Comment: sort of worked, but debug toolbar no longer displays

Comment: @radtek @Timo Are you insert your ip in `INTERNAL_IPS` if you access via remote location?

Comment: @ClarksonJey Its only used for IP on your internal network where you want debug context processors to do their thing plus a few other features. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#internal-ips

Comment: @radek yep. So i insert IP of testing machine, then it works fine.

Answer (score 14):

I used **reverse** instead of **reverse_lazy** to define the url parameter of a **RedirectView**.

```
class YourRedirectView(RedirectView):
    url = reverse('reversed_url')
```

Since the **urls.py** has not been initialized yet the error is coming up. Just use:

```
class YourRedirectView(RedirectView):
    url = reverse_lazy('reversed_url')
```

Comment: This is a real Django 'gotcha'.

Answer (score 2):

I've suffered a similar problem after upgrading from django 1.5 to 1.6. I'm not sure if my experience is the same as yours.

First, can you scroll up the errors, and check the `admin.autodiscover()` is what's generating the problem? Alternatively comment out this line and see if a page will load.

The problem I found was related to `wsgi.py`. Is it possible for you to post this file?

Comment: Tried commenting out the admin.autodiscover() but it didn't fix anything...cheers for the suggestion.

Comment: I would still suggest that you look at wsgi.py - If it works on the dev server but not apache/mod wsgi, then the implication is that the problem has something to do with that interface.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a very similar problem. My project works fine on the test server, but when I try to deploy to gunicorn I get the same ImproperlyConfigured error.

If I comment out the urls which include another url file (i.e. `url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),` then the rest of my urls work fine.

[UPDATE] I was able to further narrow it down to only one of my included url files, but couldn't find anything special about it. However, setting `Debug=False` in my `settings.py` file seems to have fixed for me.

Comment: Are you using django-debug-toolbar?

Comment: I was, but after reading mgrouchy's comment I disabled it and it worked even with Debug=True.

Comment: If you still want to use the toolbar, you might try following the [explicit instructions](http://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.org/en/1.0/installation.html#explicit-setup) for setting up the toolbar, if you haven't already done so. I installed the toolbar a while ago, used runserver for a bunch of dev work, and had forgotten about the potential issue with the toolbar by the time I configured for a production server.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure you have `urlpatterns` in the file you are including and that it is spelt correctly