# Django won't start on apache webserver

Tags: django, apache

I'm trying to run my django project with an apache webserver.

I get the following error:

```
Errors : The included urlconf hastahane.urls doesn't have any patterns in it`
```

If I'm running my project with the django development server there isn't any error.

Do you have an idea?

Comment: please post the traceback and the relevant lines of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check that the `DEBUG` settings is set to `False` and that you have properly filled the `ALLOWED_HOSTS` list ([see the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts)).

Also, are you using the **django-debug-toolbar**? In that case that may be the cause of the error. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21005346/276451).