# Can't use reverse url in django project

Tags: python, django, reverse

I have built a django project, and the folders are like this

```
project_dir
  django_dir
    settings.py
    urls.py
  app_dir
    urls.py
    tables.py
    views.py
```

And in tables.py I have added:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

print reverse('caseUpdate',args=[1])
```

system raised:
**The included urlconf django_dir.urls doesn't have any patterns in it**

BUT I used reverse in django shell, it works !

Where can I start to debug this ?

---

print out my urls.py

**django_dir --> urls.py as below:**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin

from django_dir import settings

from django.conf.urls.static import static

# xadmin, powerful and elegent admin system written by chinese
import xadmin


from xadmin.plugins import xversion
xversion.register_models()

admin.autodiscover()
xadmin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:

    url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*?)$','django.views.static.serve',{
        'document_root':settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^dispute/',include('dispute.urls')),
    url(r'xadmin/', include(xadmin.site.urls)),
)
```

**app_dir --> urls.py as below:**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from app_dir import views


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$',views.dashboard,name='dashboard'),
    url(r'^(?P<caseId>\d+)refund/',views.refund,name='refund'),
    url(r'^(?P<caseId>\d+)reply/',views.reply,name='reply'),
    url(r'^(?P<caseId>\d+)/update',views.caseUpdate,name='caseUpdate'),
    url(r'^(?P<caseId>\d+)/statuUpdate',views.statuUpdate,name='statuUpdate'),
    url(r'^(?P<caseId>\d+)/performanceUpdate',views.performanceUpdate,name='performanceUpdate'),
    url(r'^(?P<caseId>\d+)/',views.detail,name='detail'),
    url(r'^search/',views.dashboard,name='case_search'),
)
```

Comment: can you print your urls.py

Comment: It it setting.py and url.py or settings.py and urls.py ???

Comment: @SudipKafle I just edited my description,  it's settings.py and urls.py for sure, i wrote wrongly before.

Comment: @levi thx for concerning, i updated both urls.py

Comment: You're passing an "arg", but your URL expect a kwarg named "caseId".

Comment: @xbello thanks for your remind, i just tried use `print reverse('caseUpdate',kwargs={'caseId':10}) ` in my tables.py , raised same exception , which means the problem did lay in args or kwargs ?

Comment: When this happens the traceback includes something like "I tried the following patterns: (...and lots of patters here)". If you see your pattern here, you're calling it wrongly. If you don't see it, it's somehow not included in the URL dispatching.

Comment: @xbello can you explain it more detailed ?

Comment: Try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011179/django-the-included-urlconf-doesnt-have-any-patterns-in-it and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20963856/improperlyconfigured-the-included-urlconf-project-urls-doesnt-have-any-patte