# ImportError: No module named config (did you rename settings/local-dist.py?) when i try any command

Tags: python, django

In my project I have `Settings` folder. Inside that folder I put `base.py`, `local.py`, `shell.py`, `test.py`. When I try to run server it show me `no module name config` error. When I run any command like `python manage.py shell` or `manage.py runserver`.

```
__init__.py
""" Settings for online24 """

from .base import *
try:
    from .local import *
except ImportError as exc:
    exc.args = tuple(
        ['%s (did you rename settings/local-dist.py?)' % exc.args[0]])
    raise exc

Shell.py

from .dev import *

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'cmsonline',
        'USER': 'postgres1',
        'PASSWORD': 'online244',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432'
    },
}

test.py

from .base import *


DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.sqlite3",
        "NAME": ":memory:",
        "USER": "",
        "PASSWORD": "",
        "HOST": "",
        "PORT": "",
    },
}

SECRET_KEY = '{{ secret_key }}'

local.py

from . import base
import config
INSTALLED_APPS = base.INSTALLED_APPS + ('django_nose',)

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': config.DB_ENGINE,
        'NAME': config.DB_DATABASE,
        'USER': config.DB_USERNAME,
        'PASSWORD': config.DB_PASSWORD,
        'HOST': config.DB_HOST,
        'PORT': config.DB_PORT,

    },
    },
}

)
MANAGERS = ADMINS

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'

CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache',
    }
}

DEBUG = TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True


DEV = True


ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


SECRET_KEY = '{{ secret_key }}'

LOGGING_CONFIG = None
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'loggers': {
        'online24': {
            'level': "DEBUG"
        }
    }
}

INTERNAL_IPS = ('127.0.0.1')

base.py

import os
import logging

from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

def get_env_setting(setting):
    """ Get the environment setting or return exception """
    try:
        return os.environ[setting]
    except KeyError:
        error_msg = "Set the %s env variable" % setting
        raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)


# Your project root
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__) + "../../../")

SUPPORTED_NONLOCALES = ['media', 'admin', 'static']


LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

# Defines the views served for root URLs.
ROOT_URLCONF = 'online24.urls'

# Application definition
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    # Django contrib apps
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'django.contrib.syndication',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',




    'imagekit',
    'base',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'online24',
    'allauth.socialaccount',

)

# Place bcrypt first in the list, so it will be the default password hashing
# mechanism
PASSWORD_HASHERS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptSHA256PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptPasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2SHA1PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.SHA1PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.MD5PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.CryptPasswordHasher',
)


SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True


SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/home/media/media.example.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'media')

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://media.example.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.example.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static')

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.example.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale
USE_L10N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not use timezone-aware datetimes.
USE_TZ = True

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# If running in a Windows environment this must be set to the same as your
# system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    #'compressor.finders.CompressorFinder',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    #'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
]

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    #'django.core.context_processors.debug',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    'django.core.context_processors.csrf',
    'django.core.context_processors.tz',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
]

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or
    # "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'templates'),
)

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)

TEST_RUNNER = 'django.test.runner.DiscoverRunner'


def custom_show_toolbar(request):
    """ Only show the debug toolbar to users with the superuser flag. """
    return request.user.is_superuser


DEBUG_TOOLBAR_CONFIG = {
    'INTERCEPT_REDIRECTS': False,
    'SHOW_TOOLBAR_CALLBACK': 'online24.settings.base.custom_show_toolbar',
    'HIDE_DJANGO_SQL': True,
    'TAG': 'body',
    'SHOW_TEMPLATE_CONTEXT': True,
    'ENABLE_STACKTRACES': True,
}

# Uncomment the following setting if you get an ImportError such as:
#   ImproperlyConfigured: The included urlconf projectname.urls doesn't have any patterns in it
# See:
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20963856/improperlyconfigured-the-included-urlconf-project-urls-doesnt-have-any-patte/21005346#21005346
# http://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.org/en/1.0/installation.html#explicit-setup
#DEBUG_TOOLBAR_PATCH_SETTINGS = False

# DEBUG_TOOLBAR_PANELS = (
#     #'debug_toolbar_user_panel.panels.UserPanel',
#     'debug_toolbar.panels.version.VersionDebugPanel',
#     'debug_toolbar.panels.timer.TimerDebugPanel',
#     'debug_toolbar.panels.settings_vars.SettingsVarsDebugPanel',
#     'debug_toolbar.panels.headers.HeaderDebugPanel',
#     'debug_toolbar.panels.request_vars.RequestVarsDebugPanel',
#     'debug_toolbar.panels.template.TemplateDebugPanel',
#     'debug_toolbar.panels.sql.SQLDebugPanel',
#     'debug_toolbar.panels.signals.SignalDebugPanel',
#     'debug_toolbar.panels.logger.LoggingPanel',
# )

# Specify a custom user model to use
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'online24.User'

FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS = 0o0664

# The WSGI Application to use for runserver
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'online24.wsgi.application'

# Define your database connections&
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.',
        'NAME': '',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
        #'OPTIONS': {
        #    'init_command': 'SET storage_engine=InnoDB',
        #    'charset' : 'utf8',
        #    'use_unicode' : True,
        #},
        #'TEST_CHARSET': 'utf8',
        #'TEST_COLLATION': 'utf8_general_ci',
    },
    # 'slave': {
    #     ...
    # },
}

# Uncomment this and set to all slave DBs in use on the site.
# SLAVE_DATABASES = ['slave']

# Recipients of traceback emails and other notifications.
ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@domain.com'),
)
MANAGERS = ADMINS

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
# Debugging displays nice error messages, but leaks memory. Set this to False
# on all server instances and True only for development.
DEBUG = TEMPLATE_DEBUG = False

# Is this a development instance? Set this to True on development/master
# instances and False on stage/prod.
DEV = False

# Hosts/domain names that are valid for this site; required if DEBUG is False
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
# Hardcoded values can leak through source control.
# This is an example method of getting the value from an environment setting.
# Uncomment to use, and then make sure you set the SECRET_KEY environment variable.
# This is good to use in production, and on services that support it such as Heroku.
#SECRET_KEY = get_env_setting('SECRET_KEY')

# Uncomment these to activate and customize Celery:
# CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = False  # required to activate celeryd
# BROKER_HOST = 'localhost'
# BROKER_PORT = 5672
# BROKER_USER = 'django'
# BROKER_PASSWORD = 'django'
# BROKER_VHOST = 'django'
# CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'amqp'

INTERNAL_IPS = ('127.0.0.1')

# Enable this option for memcached
#CACHE_BACKEND= "memcached://127.0.0.1:11211/"

# Set this to true if you use a proxy that sets X-Forwarded-Host
#USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = False

SERVER_EMAIL = "webmaster@example.com"
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = "webmaster@example.com"
SYSTEM_EMAIL_PREFIX = "[online24]"

## Log settings

LOG_LEVEL = logging.INFO
HAS_SYSLOG = True
SYSLOG_TAG = "http_app_online24"  # Make this unique to your project.
# Remove this configuration variable to use your custom logging configuration
LOGGING_CONFIG = None
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'loggers': {
        'online24': {
            'level': "DEBUG"
        }
    }
}

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    # Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of `allauth`
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',

    # `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by e-mail
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
)

SITE_ID = 1

ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'base.forms.CustomUserCreationForm'
ACCOUNT_FORMS = {'login': 'base.forms.LoginForm',}
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_EMAIL_FIELD = 'emailid'
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_ON_GET = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'username'
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/profile'
# Common Event Format logging parameters
#CEF_PRODUCT = 'online24'
#CEF_VENDOR = 'Your Company'
#CEF_VERSION = '0'
#CEF_DEVICE_VERSION = '0'
```

Answer (score 0):

The statement `from .local import *` is failing, but in the `except` clause your code is substituting an unhelpful message for the traceback that would tell you where the real problem is.

Take out the `try/except` temporarily so that the `import` statement is allowed cause the program to fail, run again, and look at the traceback.

Comment: Yes. but in what module, and at what line? That is where your problem is. The module that is doing `import config` can't find it, so that `import` statement is incorrect. If you can't figure it out, edit your question: (1) put in the revised code and (2) report the *entire traceback*, not just the error message. Tracebacks are there to help you find problems, which is why you shouldn't suppress them.